# How to extract bounding boxes of cities from OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, extents

For simple geocoding purposes I want to extract all cities from a single country of openstreetmap.

They only queries I want to do are:

- ZipCode -> (List of) BoundingBox of City/Village
- City/Villagename -> (List of) Boundingbox of City/Village

I'm not interested in streetnames, rivers etc.
Is this possible using `osmfilter`. Can anyone point me towards the tags of the data i'm looking for?

Comment: http://overpass-turbo.eu/area can extract places Example all Cities in Belgium http://overpass-turbo.eu/?Q=area[name%3D%22Belgi%C3%AB%20-%20Belgique%20-%20Belgien%22]%3B%28node[place%3D%22city%22]%28area%29%3B%29%3Bout%3B&C=50.72255;4.10614;8

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking for the place tag http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Place and boundary http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:boundary.

You can use nominatim service http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim for geocoding as well.